# Dictionaries: checking values for selected keys

Tags: python, bioinformatics

Below you can find simple script for calculation of the protein mass in given sequence

```
import re


def make_table(yy):
    letter=r"^[A-Z]"
    mass= r"[0-9]{1,2}"
    #list of aa
    table=open(yy,'r')
    aa=[i for line in table for i in line if re.match(letter,i)]
    table.close()


    table=open(yy,'r').readlines()
    xz=''.join([line[:-1] for line in table])
    mass= re.findall(r"[-+]?\d*\.\d+|\d+", xz)


    data = dict(zip(aa, mass))
    #print data
    calc_mass(seq, data)


def calc_mass(seq, data):
    mass=[]
    test=[]

    for key, value in data.iteritems():
        for aa in seq:
            if aa==key:
                #print aa, value #debug
                test.append(aa)
                mass.append(float(value))
    if test==seq:
        print "OK!"

    mass_value=sum(mass)
    print "The protein mass is %f" %(mass_value)


# DATASET
yy="table.txt"
input=open("sequence.txt",'r').readline().strip()

seq=list(input)

make_table(yy)
```

Its based on the given sequence and the table where each mass for each amino acid are listed. Briefly it takes some text table.txt data which looks like

```
A   71.03711
C   103.00919
D   115.02694
E   129.04259
F   147.06841
G   57.02146
H   137.05891
I   113.08406
K   128.09496
L   113.08406
M   131.04049
N   114.04293
P   97.05276
Q   128.05858
R   156.10111
S   87.03203
T   101.04768
V   99.06841
W   186.07931
Y   163.06333
```

and convert it to the dictionary and then find in the given sequence the corresponeded masses for the given aa. This script works perfect except that it could not pass

```
if test==seq:
    print "OK!"
```

because the order of the amino acids in seq and in the test variables are differ. How I could restore the initial order (given in seq) after such iterations (obtained in test)? Does it any other possibilities to check values for the selected keys and move it to separate list?

Thanks for help,

Gleb

Comment: could you explain like this is the input and this is what i expect, and how your sequence.txt looks like. that will be easier to understand.

Comment: Please provide example `seq` and `data`. If `make_table` works, you can remove it entirely from your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. 
While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, 
they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. 
A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, 
example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). 
The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask]

Answer (score 1):

Rather than iterating through the whole of `data` and checking whether the `key` matches anything in `seq`, actually *use the fact that it's a dictionary*:

```
for aa in seq:
    mass.append(float(data[aa]))
```

Now `mass` will be in the same order as `seq` - this will raise a `KeyError` if any `aa` can't be found in `data`.

Comment: Thanks for advise. I did such iterations in order for operate both with keys and values in dict. In you example you show how to append values in [mass] for the corresponded keys in seq Does it possible to make the same for the keys (to obtain list of keys for which values have been appended in the same order as in the seq for instance)?

Comment: @user3470313 you already have that, it's just `seq`! Otherwise, if the key can't be found, a `KeyError` is thrown.